# How do I repeat a string?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

What I am trying to do is repeat this string:

```
                fs.writeFileSync ('./no.txt', contents, 
                       id.send(read)
                );
```

I have tried adding the repeat function

```
                fs.writeFileSync ('./no.txt', contents, 
                       id.send(read)
                ).repeat(1);
```

and what I got from it was this error:
(node:36840) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'repeat' of undefined

I am using the latest version of Node. Here's all of my code in case it's needed:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const prefix = '*';

bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Hi!')
})
bot.on("message", async message => {
   
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

        switch(args[0]){
            case 'archive' :
                

                const contents = `${message.content.slice(8)}\n`; 

                fs.appendFileSync ('./archives.txt', contents,
                   message.channel.send("Message archived")
                );

                const read = fs.readFileSync('./no.txt', {"encoding": "utf-8"});
                const id = bot.channels.cache.get('728277105904844840');

                fs.writeFileSync ('./no.txt', contents, 
                       id.send(read)
                ).repeat(1);
;
                break;

                case 'get' :
                    const thingy = new Discord.MessageAttachment('./archives.txt');
                    message.channel.send(thingy);
                    break;
        }
})
```

Comment: If you want to repeat the *contents* written to the file, then `contents.repeat(2)`. NB: `.repeat(1)` will not actually *repeat* anything. The argument represents the total number of times the string is used in the result.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with await/asinc, promise/resolve.
How about putting result in `var`, and then `repeat`?
Such as: `var result= await fs.writeFileSync ('./no.txt', contents, 
                       id.send(read)
                );`
Does it even return a `String`?
If so, then:
`result.repeat(1)`.
Actually, why `repeat(1)`?!?  It does nothing - even on a `String`!
And I don't see you doing anything with it...
`"ABC".repeat(2)` returns `"ABCABC"` - are you using `repeat` correctly, or is it something special for discord that I'm not aware of?

Comment: The `repeat()` method returns a new string with a specified number of copies of the string it was called on. And `fs.writeFileSync` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```js
fs.writeFileSync('./no.txt'.repeat(5), contents,
  id.send(read)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I didn't need to repeat it, instead what I had to do was abandon using FIleSystem and just do `id.send.contents`